# Canonical Rust equivalent to C++ capture `this` in closure

Tags: rust, closures, self

I'm having trouble finding an equivalent to this type of code, which makes me suspect it isn't idiomatic for Rust, but it's unclear what the canonical approach would be since I can't find instances of the problem discussed.

Consider this struct:

```rust
struct Looper {
    shared_value: Arc<AtomicU64>,
    handle: Option<JoinHandle<()>>
}

impl Looper {
    pub fn new(task: Box<dyn Fn() + Send>) -> Self {
        let mut looper = Self { shared_value: Arc::new(AtomicU64::new(10)), handle: None };
        let shared_state = looper.shared_value.clone();

        looper.handle = Some(thread::spawn(move || {
            for _ in 0..1000 {
                sleep(Duration::from_millis(shared_state.load(Relaxed)));
                task();
            }
        }));

        looper
    }

    pub fn set_value(&self, value: u64) {
        self.shared_value.store(value, Relaxed)
    }
}

impl Drop for Looper {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.handle.take().unwrap().join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

And consider a very contrived problem, where we want a wrapper object that can reuse the struct but it manages changes to the sleep period internally to the wrapper.

In C++, this is straightforward by capturing `this` in your lambda:

```cpp
class Wrapper {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Looper> looper;

public:
    Wrapper(Duration pollingRate, const std::function<uint64_t()>& task) {
        looper = std::make_unique<Looper>( [this, task]() { looper->set_value(task()); });
    }
}
```

In Rust, there are two issues. First, there is no constructor equivalent to capture `this` in. That type of issue is solvable by using options. I could create a `None` element first, then try to create a closure and capture the object currently set to `None` e.g.

```
struct WrappedLooper {
    looper: Option<Looper>
}

impl WrappedLooper {
    pub fn new(task: Box<dyn Fn() -> u64 + Send>) -> Self {
        let mut wrapped = WrappedLooper { looper: None };
        let this = &wrapped;

        wrapped.looper = Some(Looper::new(Box::new(move || {
            this.looper.unwrap().set_value(task());
        })));

        wrapped
    }
}
```

This obviously doesn't work as you can't move out of `this`. I could switch the internal state to an Arc and Mutex it, but this seems extremely heavy handed and incorrect to me:

```
struct WrappedLooper {
    looper: Arc<Mutex<Option<Looper>>>
}

impl WrappedLooper {
    pub fn new(task: Box<dyn Fn() -> u64 + Send>) -> Self {
        let mut wrapped = WrappedLooper { looper: Arc::new(Mutex::new(None)) };
        let copy = wrapped.looper.clone();

        wrapped.looper.lock().unwrap().replace(Looper::new(Box::new(move || {
            copy.lock().unwrap().as_mut().as_ref().unwrap().set_value(task());
        })));

        wrapped
    }
}
```

So what I am wondering is what is the right way to have this kind of self-referential initialization (the option, or something else) in scenarios where the access is always safe? (Here it is safe because the object outlives the closure + the shared mutable state is atomic)

Comment: I believe your C++ code has a data race (aside from the bug I talked about in my answer). Which just demonstrates how hard it is to write correct concurrent programs, and why you need Rust...

Comment: Agreed on the rust bit :) When I did a minimal repro I made it too minimal and didn't capture the join handle in drop. Let me know if that still is wrong in rust, but the intention was to treat the thread as a child and we wait for it to exit before dropping Looper

Comment: Mentioned this in the below discussion, but copying here: I believe there isn't tooling in the standard library for telling Rust that your struct will outlive the thread, even if you join on drop: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24292

Answer (score 4):

From my understanding, there are two separate issues. One has to do with the lifetime of the spawned thread; the other is self-reference.

Let's disregard that first issue by ignoring the thread entirely. First, let's try only requiring that the closure live as long as `Looper::new`:

```rs
    pub fn new<'a>(_task: Box<dyn Fn() + Send + Sync + 'a>) -> Self {
        Self {
            shared_value: Arc::new(AtomicU64::new(10)),
        }
    }
```

Then, [everything else compiles just fine](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a20b14bdd12ba7758cf13b8c3a286b30). But this isn't very useful: if we aren't guaranteed that the function lives past `Looper::new`, we obviously can't use it in the thread. Instead, we could tell Rust that `task` must live as long as the created `Looper`:

```rs
struct Looper<'a> {
    shared_value: Arc<AtomicU64>,
    _marker: PhantomData<dyn Fn() + Send + Sync + 'a>,
}

impl<'a> Looper<'a> {
    pub fn new(_task: Box<dyn Fn() + Send + Sync + 'a>) -> Self {
        Self {
            shared_value: Arc::new(AtomicU64::new(10)),
            _marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }

    pub fn set_value(&self, value: u64) {
        self.shared_value.store(value, Relaxed)
    }
}
```

Then, the immediate issue is that we want `WrappedLooper` to have an instance of `Looper` that depends on a reference to itself. We can't freely let `Looper` do that: what happens to that self-reference if `Looper` is moved? So, making this work would require some unsafe Rust using `Pin`, or at least a library that encapsulates that away.

However, even if this were implemented, we hit the other problem: there's no way to really know how long the thread lives. Let's add the thread spawning back in:

```
11 |   impl<'a> Looper<'a> {
   |        -- lifetime `'a` defined here
12 |       pub fn new(task: Box<dyn Fn() + Send + Sync + 'a>) -> Self {
   |                  ---- `task` is a reference that is only valid in the associated function body
...
20 | /         thread::spawn(move || {
21 | |             sleep(Duration::from_millis(shared_state.load(Relaxed)));
22 | |             task();
23 | |         });
   | |          ^
   | |          |
   | |__________`task` escapes the associated function body here
   |            argument requires that `'a` must outlive `'static`
```

([Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3499522cdab4f0cb74b8321cd18b1d21))

Telling Rust that our function lives as long as `Looper` is not enough: it has to be `'static`. This makes sense: consider what happens if `WrappedLooper` is dropped before the delay is over. Then, `task` could no longer hold a reference to the looper. *The C++ snippet has exactly this problem: if the `Wrapper` is destroyed, then the `this` captured in the `task` for the `Looper` is now dangling.*

Because Rust does not provide a way to guarantee the looper instance indeed outlives the thread, it's probably best to just use reference counting here.

---

Sidenote:

> In Rust, there are two issues. First, there is no constructor equivalent to capture `this` in. That type of issue is solvable by using options.

This first issue is also present in the C++ version, just hidden. In C++, `unique_ptr` can be null (and starts null). So, it acts just like an `Option`, where `looper->set_value` in C++ is essentially equivalent to `looper.unwrap_unchecked().set_value` in Rust. The difference is that Rust forces us to explicitly recognize it.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! Unfortunately, you did make me realize I made an error when converting the actual code in question to a smaller repro. In the original hypothetical, there's definitely a dangling pointer issue which I've resolved. The thread isn't intended to outlive the Looper.

In that paradigm where Looper drop joins the thread there is no longer a dangling reference. WrappedLooper owns Looper which owns a thread handle which own closure Task which owns a reference back to Looper. Since we wait for the thread, that tree should walk itself back fine.

Comment: In that scenario, is it worth trying to get the lifetimes right (which is a weak area as a rust beginner and I'd try more on my own first) or is the borrow checker never satisfied by that type of ownership chain?

As I write rust code that I could write safely in C++ I'm trying to keep in mind:
1. Sometimes I make mistakes
2. I'm more familiar with C++ so I can usually write safe code, in rust since it's new to me I'm more likely to mess up unsafe rust than C++
3. Often times "needing" unsafe is really just "I don't know how to do it in rust yet"

Comment: I think the hardest part of switching from C++ mindset is that in Rust I can just "cheat" by reference counting everything even though it isn't always necessary, and it's hard to tell when I should be trying to get better at the lifetime annotations vs no, it really is just better to reference count here because the minor optimization isn't worth the unsafe block

Comment: Unfortunately, in Rust, you will probably be stuck reference counting. I don't think there is a way to make the lifetimes work out, even if it might be safe. Unless you use a scoped thread, which won't work here, there is no way to have the closure's lifetime be anything but `'static` to associate it with the Looper. There USED to be `std::thread::JoinGuard`, but that got axed before the first stable release.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of issue can be solved with [`Arc::new_cyclic()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.new_cyclic):

```rust
struct WrappedLooper {
    looper: Arc<Looper>,
}

impl WrappedLooper {
    pub fn new(task: Box<dyn Fn() -> u64 + Send>) -> Self {
        let looper = Arc::<Looper>::new_cyclic(|looper| {
            let looper = Weak::clone(looper);
            Looper::new(Box::new(move || {
                let looper = looper.upgrade().expect("looper gone");
                looper.set_value(task());
            }))
        });

        WrappedLooper { looper }
    }
}
```

However, this code has an issue, that is also present in your C++ code and Rust code with the `Mutex` (in both Rust snippets it can cause panic, in the C++ snippet it can cause UB): if the thread will start running before we'll complete the `Looper` construction, we will see a null `Looper` (this will cause a panic in the `unwrap()` in your Rust snippet or in the `upgrade().expect()` in my Rust snippet, and UB in C++ as we'll try to dereference a null pointer). This can be solved with a channel:

```rust
impl WrappedLooper {
    pub fn new(task: Box<dyn Fn() -> u64 + Send>) -> Self {
        let (construction_completed_tx, construction_completed_rx) = mpsc::sync_channel(1);
        let looper = Arc::<Looper>::new_cyclic(|looper| {
            let looper = Weak::clone(looper);
            Looper::new(Box::new(move || {
                construction_completed_rx.recv().expect("looper gone");
                
                let looper = looper.upgrade().expect("looper gone");
                looper.set_value(task());
            }))
        });
        construction_completed_tx.send(()).unwrap();

        WrappedLooper { looper }
    }
}
```